# How can I press multiple keys (COMMAND, SHIFT, l) with selenium+tor+firefox?

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I'm scraping a website on tor. They block the IP address I am scraping with after around a thousand requests. I've got ~200K requests to make so I'm trying to automate creating a new circuit each time the browser gets blocked and keeping it the same otherwise.

normally I can use COMMAND+SHIFT+l to create a new circuit. However that isn't working with my code.

I'm creating my driver and pressing keys as follows:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("/Applications/Tor Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = binary)

driver.get("https://torproject.com/")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.COMMAND).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys('l').perform()
```

I've also tried using `actions.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SHIFT, 'l').perform()` and `actions.key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, 'l').perform()`

the syntax does seem to be pressing the keys because I can do `actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()` and the page scrolls down.

I'm on MacOS, firefox 85.0.2, selenium 3.141.0, geckodriver 0.29.0

I could not find any related bugs in geckodriver.

Comment: One question, "creating a new circuit"? maybe you need to restart your browser, or to refresh your page, can that help?

Comment: Yes - it is essentially refreshing the page. If I manually press Command + Shift + l, it refreshes the page with a new circuit (guard node unchanged).

Comment: an this help driver.navigate().refresh(); ?

Comment: @GajJulije That's in java, C#. I'm in python which only has driver.get(). Also, refreshing the page does not create a new circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, since you're using MacOS and it's based on Unix, to change the TOR circuit by launching programmatically commands by terminal instead of simulating the pressing of the shortkey.

Take a look here: [link](http://I%20suggest%20you,%20since%20you%27re%20using%20MacOS%20and%20it%27s%20based%20on%20Unix,%20to%20change%20the%20TOR%20circuit%20by%20launching%20programmatically%20commands%20by%20terminal%20instead%20of%20simulating%20the%20pressing%20of%20the%20shortkey.)

it recites: "If you want to force Tor to generate a new circuit, and thus a new IP, use the following command: `echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE ""\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051`
"